# Google+ iOS Sign In Address Invalid

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus

There are a lot of questions about this - all have the same answer that for me didn't help.

After authenticating - I should be going back to my app via Safari.
I'm getting the "Address Invalid" error message.

My URL schemes are ok:
[image]

A "proof" that it should work is that when I manually type in Safari:
`com.Cookila.Cookila-test://` I get redirected to my app.

The code that caused the login:

```
- (IBAction)doGoogleLogin:(id)sender {
    NSString *clientID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"googleLoginKey"];
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;

    signIn.clientID = clientID;

    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];

    signIn.delegate = self;

    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... there was a mixup with the $PRODUCT_NAME / real bundle ID.
The BundleID (which g+ correctly deduces) is com.Cookila.Cookila-copy. After changing it all works

So the answer for future reference - make sure you have the readl bundle ID name in both places